# Getting blocked while trying to execute a command on Linux using c++

Tags: c++, linux, java-native-interface

I'm trying to run a command on linux and retrieve the the output and I found some code, but when I'm running it, I get the first line and then the thread get blocked. Here is the code:

```
std::string exec_cmd(char const* cmd)
{
    std::string result, file;
    FILE* pipe {popen(cmd, "r")};
    char buffer[256];

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), pipe) != nullptr)
    {
        file = buffer;
        result += file.substr(0, file.size() - 1);
    }

    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```

For instance, if i'm running the command `uname -a` I get the out but the `fgets` wait for data and the execution gets stuck there.

I'm using JNI.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: N.B. that code will lose characters if there is a line longer than 256 bytes, because it always discards  the last character read from the pipe.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, surely your second example should just do `result += buffer` instead of the double copy

Comment: [WFM](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cd35986d65794aa1)! And [here's an example with clear newlines](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ef008180e8f10d0) (after fixing your errant `-1`).

Answer (score 1):

The code should work, but I would use my [`pstream.h`](http://sourceforge.net/p/pstreams/code/ci/master/tree/pstream.h) header instead:

```
std::string exec_cmd(char const* cmd)
{
    redi::ipstream p(cmd);
    std::ostringstream result;
    result << p.rdbuf();
    return result.str();
}
```

Or, if the newline-stripping behaviour of the original code is actually desired:

```
std::string exec_cmd(char const* cmd)
{
    redi::ipstream p(cmd);
    std::string result, line;
    while (std::getline(p, line))
        result += line;
    return result;
}
```

This will only strip newline characters, not lose data from lines longer than 256 bytes.

Comment: a +1 for good code & suggestions despite not technically having answered the question (which may not be possible)

Comment: Oh, I've never tried using pipes or fork/exec with JNI. I have no idea how to make that work.